# $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(2+c)^{-n}=b$ infinite series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Consider $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(2+c)^{-n}=b$. $b$ is a positive constant, and $c \in \mathbb{R}$. For which values of b does the infinite series permit a **single solution** of c? First, evaluating this series by the divergence test it has to be 0 for it to certainly converge. There's also a possibility of multiple solutions, but this is not very likely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The infinite series is a geometric series. It has a nice closed form, and has radius of convergence $1$. That is:

1. The sum converges only when $\left|\frac1 {2+c}\right| <1$, or $|2+c| > 1$, or ($c<-3$ or $c>-1$)
2. When it does converge, $\sum_{n=2}^\infty (2+c)^{-n} = \frac {(2+c)^{-2}}{1-(2+c)^{-1}} = \frac1{(2+c)(1+c)}$
3. The equation $\frac1{(2+c)(1+c)} = b$, or $(c+1)(c+2) = \frac1b$ is a quadratic equation in $c$. Any positive $b$ would yield two solutions for $c$, unless one of the solutions violates our convergence rule above.

Therefore we need to find when the quadratic equation $(c+1)(c+2)= \frac1b$ gives a solution $c\in[-3,-1]$. As one of the solutions is always greater than $-1$ and the other always less than $-2$, this invalid solution must be within $[-3, -2)$, which corresponds to $\frac1b \in (0,2]$, or $b\in[1/2,\infty)$.